# How do I make my script type="module" with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the below to link my script file, but I need to somehow add the script type="module". Any idea how to do this?

```
function theme_styles() {
    $scripts_cache = get_stylesheet_directory().'/lib/scripts/scripts.min.js';
    $stylesheet_cache = get_stylesheet_directory().'/lib/styles/css/main.min.css';

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/lib/styles/css/main.min.css', array(), filemtime($stylesheet_cache) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/lib/scripts/scripts.min.js', array(), filemtime($scripts_cache) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use script_loader_tag hook :

See the documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/

```
apply_filters( 'script_loader_tag', string $tag, string $handle, string $src )
```

For your issue :

**Use script_loader_tag**

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_attributes_to_script', 10, 3); 
function add_attributes_to_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'scripts' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" id="scripts" ></script>';
    } 
    return $tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution that does not need to review all scripts:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    $scripts_cache = filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/lib/scripts/scripts.min.js');
    $stylesheet_cache = filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory().'/lib/styles/css/main.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/lib/styles/css/main.min.css', array(), $stylesheet_cache );

    $script_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/lib/scripts/scripts.min.js?ver='.$scripts_cache;
    echo "<script src='$script_url' type='module'></script>";
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );
```